# How do I manage multiple user inputs with only one onChange in React Native?

Tags: react-native, button, onchange, textinput

How do I handle multiple text inputs with only one onChange on React Native?
For example:
Name, age, nationality, eye color.

Additionally, how do I save all of the inputs with only one button? (I want to output a list with all of these inputs in the same "item")

Here's my code with what I did so far, I want to make a sort of movie diary where the user can register new movies they want to watch: (I'm a total beginner btw, so I'm not sure about how to do most things. I'm doing this project to learn)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, View, Text, TextInput, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const Registration = props => {

    const [enteredMovieName, setMovieName] = useState("");
    const [enteredSynopsis, setSynopsis] = useState("");
    const [enteredComments, setComments] = useState("");
    const [enteredSource, setSource] = useState("");

    const movieData = {
        Name: enteredMovieName,
        Synopsis: enteredSynopsis,
        Comments: enteredComments,
        Source: enteredSource,
    };

    const movieDataHandler = () => {
        console.log(movieData);

    };


    return (
        <ScrollView>
            <View>

                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.bodyHighlight}>Add new movie</Text>
                </View>
                <ScrollView>
                    <View>
                        <Text style={styles.addMovie} >Movie name:</Text>
                        <TextInput
                            placeholder='Cool Movie Name'
                            style={styles.inputContainer}
                            onChangeText={enteredText => setMovieName(enteredText)}
                            value={enteredMovieName}

                        />
                        <Text style={styles.addMovie} >Sinopsis:</Text>
                        <TextInput
                            placeholder='Amazing Synopsis'
                            style={styles.inputContainer}
                            onChangeText={enteredText => setSynopsis(enteredText)}
                            value={enteredSynopsis}

                        />
                        <Text style={styles.addMovie} >Comments (optional):</Text>
                        <TextInput
                            placeholder='Awesome Thoughts'
                            style={styles.inputContainer}
                            onChangeText={enteredText => setComments(enteredText)}
                            value={enteredComments}

                        />
                        <Text style={styles.addMovie} >Where to watch (optional):</Text>
                        <TextInput
                            placeholder='Super Useful Link'
                            style={styles.inputContainer}
                            onChangeText={enteredText => setSource(enteredText)}
                            value={enteredSource}

                        />
                    </View>
                    <View>

                        <Button
                            style={styles.addMovie}
                            title='ADD'
                            color='#a30b00'
                            onPress={movieDataHandler}
                        />

                        <Button
                            style={styles.addMovie}
                            title='SEE COMPLETE LIST'
                            color='#cd5c5c'
                            onPress={() => {
                                props.navigation.navigate('Items Screen');
                            }}
                        />

                    </View>
                </ScrollView>

            </View >
        </ScrollView>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    bodyHighlight: {
        padding: 10,
        margin: 5,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 25,
        textAlign: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#C4BDBA'

    },
    inputContainer: {
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 2,
        width: 380,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginHorizontal: 10,
        marginBottom: 5,

    },
    addMovie: {
        padding: 10,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'stretch',
        marginHorizontal: 10,

    },

})

export default Registration;
```

Comment: Can you give a small code example of what you mean? And when you mean 'with only one onChange', do you mean with only one function that you can pass to the onChange function of each text input?

Comment: Yes! I'll add my code here to give an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a new function and make changes to the a copied object and push the new object to the state

```
const handleChange=(key,value)=>{
  const myState = user
  myState[key] = value
  setUserData(myState)
}
```

then pass the function call to `onChangeText` prop

```
    <TextInput
      style={styles.input}
      onChangeText={(text) => handleChange('name', text)}
      value={user.name}
    />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can manage all states in an object. For example:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  Alert,
} from 'react-native';

const UselessTextInput = () => {
  const [user, setUserData] = React.useState({ name: '', age: 0 });

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={(text) => setUserData({...user, name: text })}
        value={user.name}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={(age) => setUserData({...user, age: age })}
        value={user.age}
      />
      <Button onPress={() => Alert.alert(`User name ${user.name}, age ${user.age}`)} title="click me" />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    height: 40,
    marginTop: 42,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
});

export default UselessTextInput;
```